# AWS Lambda function not working with sequelize and sqlite3

Tags: amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, node-sqlite3

I have a AWS Lambda function that uses sequelize with sqlite. The application runs fine locally (Mac), but when I deploy it to Lambda, I get the error:

`Please install sqlite3 package manually`

Looks like the error is coming from sequelize:

```
  "stackTrace": [
    "new ConnectionManager (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js:22:21)",
    "new SqliteDialect (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/index.js:14:30)",
    "new Sequelize (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:320:20)",
(...)
```

sqlite3 is in the package.json.

I understand that sqlite3 has binary dependencies that need to be compiled with node-gyp. I tried to manually compile sqlite3 by running node-pre-gyp from within the sqlite3 folder in node_modules using a Vagrant Linux machine, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: package.json: https://gist.github.com/raisen/23a08f35d131ac094212e3d414726cc5

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the node version I used locally didn't match with AWS and therefore the compiled files were in different directories.